# Watch FTP directory file additions as drive letter

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to watch a FTP server with node so that some files get read when they're added. Since the FTP doesn't have any API to notify these additions, can I assign it to a drive letter (for instance, with WebDrive) and watch it as if it had an API?

Answer (score 2):

No.

As you know *"FTP doesn't have any API to notify"*.

So how would mapping the FTP to a drive *magically* become aware of the changes?